# Sort badges by gold/silver/bronze and earned/unearned simultaneously

Tags: feature-request, badges, sorting

Currently, we can sort badges by choosing among "all", "earned", "unearned", "gold", "silver", or "bronze". However, these are not all mutually exclusive categories. It would be nice if we could toggle these options separately, e.g. to sort by "bronze/unearned".

Is this a sensible potential update? It's a small change but it could make the site feel a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing from gold, silver, or bronze effectively does this. It groups them by type and puts a check mark next to those you've earned.

---

Having said that, if this level of detail is desired, providing filters would accomplish what you want.

When bringing up the badge list, a list of filters could be shown:

[x]Earned    [x]Unearned    [x]Gold    [x]Silver   [x]Bronze

You could then select and deselect individual filters as you wished.